# Programmable RFID card

Tags: raspberry-pi, arduino, encryption, rfid

I'm new to RFID technology and cryptography. So, I'm trying to apply light weight cryptography in RFID tags as a part of my project.

I'm already able to read and write information in some passive RFID tags. But I'm looking for a programmable RFID tag similar to a smart card. Basically I want to send some data to the tag and the tag itself encrypts the data and stores it in its memory. When I want to read the data, it decrypts it and sends it to the reader.

I've searched all over the internet and it isn't helping much.
Can someone give any suggestions on where can I find such card and how can I program it?

Comment: May I ask: What is the reason behind the tag holding all the data?

Comment: @SiXandSeven8ths this is a project that I have been assigned in order to learn lightweight cryptography. Currently the task is just to run simple encryption algorithms in the RFID tag. I'm not much aware of where this data is going to be used later on.